# Code Coverage: Why is end marker red (End If, End Try, ...)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, mstest, code-coverage

I use MS-Test with Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Basic.

In the following function the Code Coverage tells me, that there is one unchecked block and the line with the **"End Try"** is red (see http://lts.cr/BVvP):

```
Private Function GetLatestVersionInfoForAsync()

    Try
        Return GetLatestVersionInfo()
    Catch ex As Exception
        RaiseEvent UnhandledAsyncException(Me, New UnhandledExceptionEventArgs(ex, False))
        Return New VersionInfo() With {.ExceptionOccoured = True, .Exception = ex}
    End Try

End Function
```

So, why is this "End Try" line an uncovered (red) block (the same happens to "End If" at the end of a function)?

Another question I have: Is there any resource that explains the different colors of in the code coverage results (blue is clear, but I have seen yellow, dark and light red, ...).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further to Daniel's point on sequence points it's worth looking at this further. If we take a simple function that repeats what you are doing

```
07    Function Method() As String
08        Try
09           Return ""
10        Catch ex As Exception
11           Return ""
12       End Try
13    End Function
```

In Debug we get the following sequence points (I am using [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) for this)

```
<SequencePoints> 
  <SequencePoint offset="0" ordinal="0" uspid="261" vc="0" ec="32" el="7" sc="5" sl="7"/> 
  <SequencePoint offset="1" ordinal="1" uspid="262" vc="0" ec="12" el="8" sc="9" sl="8"/> 
  <SequencePoint offset="2" ordinal="2" uspid="263" vc="0" ec="22" el="9" sc="13" sl="9"/> 
  <SequencePoint offset="19" ordinal="3" uspid="264" vc="0" ec="30" el="10" sc="9" sl="10"/> 
  <SequencePoint offset="20" ordinal="4" uspid="265" vc="0" ec="22" el="11" sc="13" sl="11"/> 
  <SequencePoint offset="40" ordinal="5" uspid="266" vc="0" ec="16" el="12" sc="9" sl="12"/> 
  <SequencePoint offset="41" ordinal="6" uspid="267" vc="0" ec="17" el="13" sc="5" sl="13"/> 
</SequencePoints>
```

(where sl = start line, el = end line, sc = start column, ec = end column and offset = IL offset in decimal)

However these only make sense when you look at the IL

```
.method public static 
    string Method () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x272c
    // Code size 43 (0x2b)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] string Method,
        [1] class [mscorlib]System.Exception ex
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: nop
    .try
    {
        IL_0002: ldstr ""
        IL_0007: stloc.0
        IL_0008: leave.s IL_0029

        IL_000a: leave.s IL_0028
    } // end .try
    catch [mscorlib]System.Exception
    {
        IL_000c: dup
        IL_000d: call void [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData::SetProjectError(class [mscorlib]System.Exception)
        IL_0012: stloc.1
        IL_0013: nop
        IL_0014: ldstr ""
        IL_0019: stloc.0
        IL_001a: call void [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData::ClearProjectError()
        IL_001f: leave.s IL_0029

        IL_0021: call void [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData::ClearProjectError()
        IL_0026: leave.s IL_0028
    } // end handler

    IL_0028: nop

    IL_0029: ldloc.0
    IL_002a: ret
} // end of method Module1::Method
```

Now as you can see the `End Try` line you are concerned about would only be marked as hit if you hit the IL instruction at offset 40 (IL_0028) however when you look at the IL produced I cant see how you would ever get there due to the odd IL produced (`leave.s` is a small jump like instruction that is used to exit try/catch/finally blocks) and if you follow the code you see that you will always reach a `leave.s` that jumps to IL_0029 first.

In release the IL changes

```
.method public static 
    string Method () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2274
    // Code size 30 (0x1e)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] string Method,
        [1] class [mscorlib]System.Exception ex
    )

    .try
    {
        IL_0000: ldstr ""
        IL_0005: stloc.0
        IL_0006: leave.s IL_001c
    } // end .try
    catch [mscorlib]System.Exception
    {
        IL_0008: dup
        IL_0009: call void [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData::SetProjectError(class [mscorlib]System.Exception)
        IL_000e: stloc.1
        IL_000f: ldstr ""
        IL_0014: stloc.0
        IL_0015: call void [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData::ClearProjectError()
        IL_001a: leave.s IL_001c
    } // end handler

    IL_001c: ldloc.0
    IL_001d: ret
} // end of method Module1::Method
```

and so do the sequence points

```
<SequencePoints> 
  <SequencePoint offset="0" ordinal="0" uspid="33" vc="0" ec="22" el="9" sc="13" sl="9"/> 
  <SequencePoint offset="15" ordinal="1" uspid="34" vc="0" ec="22" el="11" sc="13" sl="11"/> 
  <SequencePoint offset="28" ordinal="2" uspid="35" vc="0" ec="17" el="13" sc="5" sl="13"/> 
</SequencePoints>
```

So you sort of loose either way as now you will never see your try/catch lines marked covered

So lets try changing your code as suggested by Hans and go back to debug (because that is where you will be running coverage from usually)

```
15   Function Method2() As String
16        Dim x As String
17        Try
18            x = ""
19        Catch ex As Exception
20            x = ""
21        End Try
22        Return x
23    End Function
```

Again we look at the sequence points

```
<SequencePoints> 
  <SequencePoint offset="0" ordinal="0" uspid="268" vc="0" ec="33" el="15" sc="5" sl="15"/>
  <SequencePoint offset="1" ordinal="1" uspid="269" vc="0" ec="12" el="17" sc="9" sl="17"/> 
  <SequencePoint offset="2" ordinal="2" uspid="270" vc="0" ec="19" el="18" sc="13" sl="18"/> 
  <SequencePoint offset="17" ordinal="3" uspid="271" vc="0" ec="30" el="19" sc="9" sl="19"/> 
  <SequencePoint offset="18" ordinal="4" uspid="272" vc="0" ec="19" el="20" sc="13" sl="20"/> 
  <SequencePoint offset="31" ordinal="5" uspid="273" vc="0" ec="16" el="21" sc="9" sl="21"/> 
  <SequencePoint offset="32" ordinal="6" uspid="274" vc="0" ec="17" el="22" sc="9" sl="22"/> 
  <SequencePoint offset="36" ordinal="7" uspid="275" vc="0" ec="17" el="23" sc="5" sl="23"/> 
</SequencePoints>
```

and the IL

```
.method public static 
    string Method2 () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x282c
    // Code size 38 (0x26)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] string Method2,
        [1] string x,
        [2] class [mscorlib]System.Exception ex
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: nop
    .try
    {
        IL_0002: ldstr ""
        IL_0007: stloc.1
        IL_0008: leave.s IL_001f
    } // end .try
    catch [mscorlib]System.Exception
    {
        IL_000a: dup
        IL_000b: call void [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData::SetProjectError(class [mscorlib]System.Exception)
        IL_0010: stloc.2
        IL_0011: nop
        IL_0012: ldstr ""
        IL_0017: stloc.1
        IL_0018: call void [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData::ClearProjectError()
        IL_001d: leave.s IL_001f
    } // end handler

    IL_001f: nop
    IL_0020: ldloc.1
    IL_0021: stloc.0
    IL_0022: br.s IL_0024

    IL_0024: ldloc.0
    IL_0025: ret
} // end of method Module1::Method2
```

So for your `End Try` to be covered we need line 21 to be hit and that is offset 31 (IL_001F) and as we can see both `leave.s` instructions jump to that point so now that line will be marked as covered.

So both Hans and Daniel are correct and I hope the above explains why

Comment: You're welcome, I'll probably turn this into a blog post as well

Answer (score 3):

Before control passes that `End Try` line, it reaches the `Return` line and exits the function. So (as far as Code coverage is concerned) you never reach that line. Not that it is any problem in this case.

A workaround would be to hold that VersionInfo in a single temp variable and return that *after* the End Try. A guess (I'm used to C#, not VB):

```
Private Function GetLatestVersionInfoForAsync()
    Dim vi As VersionInfo
    Try
        vi = GetLatestVersionInfo()
    Catch ex As Exception
        RaiseEvent UnhandledAsyncException(Me, New UnhandledExceptionEventArgs(ex, False))
        vi = New VersionInfo() With {.ExceptionOccoured = True, .Exception = ex}
    End Try
    Return vi
End Function
```

Comment: it is also bad practice to have returns strewn everywhere. in 99% of cases you should set a return variable as above and return it at the end.

Answer (score 2):

The PDB file of your assembly contains the information which IL instructions corresponds to which line(s) of your original source code. This piece of information is called a sequence point.
But not every line in your code corresponds exactly to one sequence point.
Your test coverage is calculated based on the sequence points, so it could happen that lines of your code appear uncovered although they were executed during your test.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used MS-Test but it will be flagging "New VersionInfo()" as unchecked.